# イ音便 Outside of the て and た Forms

Tags: verbs, phonetics

I understand that a lot of the time the consonants in き, ぎ, し and り were dropped, making 書きて into 書いて, 焼き刃 into やいば, 良し into 良い, etc.
When it comes to verbs, it affected their て form as well as た/たら/たり, did it affect other uses of the 連用形?

Like how 引き+越す gives us 引っ越す, K+K geminates regularly in the same way that 積+極 becomes せっきょく. But I can't find any instances of イ音便 in verbal compounds, and it doesn't happen with たい either. Why's that?

Comment: Like 埼玉 from 埼 and 玉?

Comment: @aguijonazo  Specifically verbal compounds, or other uses or the 連用形. Think of something like ござるーござい.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [presentation](http://www.kyorin-u.ac.jp/univ/user/foreign/nikodebu/lectures(PDF)/2-4.pdf), which is based on a book titled 日本語構造伝達文法・発展Ａ, touches upon why 音便 doesn’t happen in the たい-form (e.g. 書きたい).

If my interpretation is correct, the reason the /t/ sound doesn't affect the sound of the preceding verb in the たい-form is that たい, as a semantic unit to express the subject’s desire that the event described by the verb materializes, is more independent from, and therefore, less closely associated with the verb than the て of the て-form, which, as an aspect marker, is a more integral part of the verb itself. Thus, 書きて (before 音便) forms one unbreakable semantic unit, so to speak, whereas 書きたい doesn't, and energy-saving phonetic changes, such as that from 書きて to 書いて, don’t easily transcend boundaries of such units.

Comment: It's also worth noting the historical phonetics of the ～たい ending -- this developed from older ～いたし, same as modern 痛【いた】い ("painful").  I suspect that the initial い in いたし is also partly why this suffix did not lead to イ音便【おんびん】.

Answer (score 2):

Well, Frellesvig (2010, p. 196, n. 3) is very uncomfortable with the traditional  explanation of [一日]{ついたち} as "[月]{つき}[立]{た}ち" as that would contradict the general principle that the syllables with the historical ï vowel (second i) do not have 音便. As an alternative, he proposes an etymologization through [着]{つ}き[発]{た}ち "arrival (of a new moon) and departure (of the previous)", which has your deletion before i.

Reference:

Frellesvig, Bjarke. *A history of the Japanese language.* Cambridge University Press, 2010.