# Why doesn't the て form of a verb connect to たい?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, history

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_grammar#Verb_conjugations), the て form is the result of sound changes that occurred when the 連用形 proceeded the particle て.

| Historical | Contemporary |
| --- | --- |
| 買いて | 買って |
| 打ちて | 打って |
| 知りて | 知って |
| 遊びて | 遊んで |
| 住みて | 住んで |
| 死にて | 死んで |
| 書きて | 書いて |
| 泳ぎて | 泳いで |

We can see the same sound change occurring before other particles starting with a "t" sound: た, たら, and たり.  My question is straight forward, why doesn't this sound change also occur before the auxiliary verb, たい?

Historically, is there any reason why the construction 死にたい has resisted this sound change and hasn't become 死んだい?

Comment: This isn't really a regular sound change in the language. Rather, 〜たい attaches to the stem, while 〜て does not.

Comment: @jogloran But historically, as OP points out, ～て, ～た, ～たり *do* attach to the 連用形, and there is nothing super phonetically dissimilar about them and ～たい

Comment: Related: [イ音便 Outside of the て and た Forms](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/92646/43676)

Comment: Thanks, @aguijonazo!  That was exactly my question.

Comment: @Angelos Yes, but it's not a regular sound change — if it were, I would expect a sound rule like /nite/ -> /nde/, but it's just not conditioned by the phonetic environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically, derivationally, the desiderative ending ～たい comes from 痛【いた】い.  This is speculation on my part -- the phonology of that initial //i// in //itai// may have prevented the gemination that developed in Eastern Japanese forms like 買【か】って, or the fusion (or contraction?) that we see in 死【し】んで.

Note that Western Japanese often has ～うて・～うた, where Eastern (i.e. "Standard" or 標準語【ひょうじゅんご】, i.e. Tokyo) Japanese has ～って・った.  Eastern 買【か】って shows up in Western (Kansai, anyway) as 買【こ】うて, for example.

Comment: Kansai = **West** of the Barrier

Comment: @aguijonazo: GAH.  Grew up on the east coast, moved to the west coast, and realized that my internal concept of "east / west" had to do with which side the ocean was on -- and moving to the other side of the continent has caused me to consistently get that backwards.    Fixing momentarily!

Comment: I can understand why alveolar り and ち caused gemination on て or た, which is also alveolar, but I have been wondering why い (historically bilabial ひ) also caused it. かいて is not hard to pronounce. 書きて became that, after all. Any idea?

Comment: @aguijonazo: My only historical comparison text at present is the _Nippo Jisho_, which appears to record Western Japanese, which never seems to have developed this gemination.  I wonder if Eastern Japanese may have retained the medial //f// for longer, which may have affected the phonology? So rather than 買【か】う as //kau//, maybe it was 買【か】ふ as //kafu// (technically [[kaɸu]]), so //kafi// + //te// → //kafite// → //kafte// → //katte//?

Comment: It’s kind of like the word for *Baptist* being *battista* in Italian and *bautista* in Spanish (although it’s also spelled *baptista*). It could be due to the difference in the tendency to devoice vowels. 上方言葉 is more 母音がち than 標準語, meaning vowels are less likely to be devoiced, even today.

Comment: @aguijonazo: In cruder and punnier terms, Eastern Japanese speakers must get less fiber in their diet -- compared to Western Japanese, they have loose vowel movements.  

Comment: I hear soba contains more fiber than udon. That's probably why.